# Microsoft Oauth2 403 Forbidden

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

I want to access any user's calendar in my Java application.

In https://portal.azure.com, I created an Azure Active Directory: aniketorg123

Then I created an app in it: aniketorgapp1

Following are the Redirect URIs that I added:

[image]

Then I added some permissions:

[image]

Now, in my application I send Oauth authorization request:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&response_mode=form_post&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8443%2Fmsal4jsample%2Fsecure%2Faad&client_id=ca146462-8880-424c-b629-cc7c0d0fb1b3&scope=openid+offline_access+profile&prompt=select_account&state=69a2ac0f-abac-46ad-b525-88f0b70182b7&nonce=9278f424-6858-4e22-bb13-7b13894abda7

This loads the "Pick an account" page. When the user picks an account, I'm getting the following response:

**403 Forbidden**

Why could I be getting 403 forbidden?

Comment: This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/cloud-partner-portal-orig/cloud-partner-portal-api-troubleshooting-authentication-errors#forbidden-error) may help in fixing the issue

Comment: @HariKrishna--MSFTIdentity Is Service Principal required for multi tenant?

Comment: @user515835, Yes Service Principal required for multi-tenant applications

Comment: @HariKrishna--MSFTIdentity I don't understand what I need to do. Do I have to Create a user of Type Service Principal? When I try to create a new user, I don't see any input for Type

Comment: @HariKrishna--MSFTIdentity My Application ID is 408c3ca0-e208-4067-b0d8-4c2c5f94f754 

Also, do I have to create account on https://cloudpartner.azure.com to make this work?

Comment: The service principle is not a user type. It is simply part of your app registration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213428/discussion-between-hari-krishna-msft-identity-and-user5155835).

Comment: Hi, may I know if this problem was solved ?

Comment: This seemed to be an issue with the sample, which should be fixed now. You can also try changing response_mode=query in the authorization url and that should fix this problem.

Comment: This was caused by some of the samesite updates that browsers are making

Comment: @sgonzalez make your comment an answer and I'll accept it. Also, not specifying the response_mode at all also works

Comment: @user5155835 Glad it worked, posted as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to be an issue with the sample, which should be fixed now. You can also try changing response_mode=query in the authorization url and that should fix this problem. This was caused by some of the samesite updates that browsers are making.

Answer (score 1):

If you get a 403 forbidden error, make sure that the correct service principal has been added to your publisher account in the Cloud Partner Portal. Follow the steps in the [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/cloud-partner-portal-orig/cloud-partner-portal-api-prerequisites) page to add your service principal to the portal.

If the correct service principal has been added, then verify all the other information. Pay close attention to the Object ID entered on the portal. There are two Object IDs in the Azure Active Directory app registration page, and you must use the local Object ID. You can find the correct value by going to the **App registrations** page for your app and clicking on the app name under **Managed application** **in local directory**. This takes you to the local **properties** for the app, where you can find the correct Object ID in the Properties page, as shown in the following figure. Also, ensure that you use the correct publisher ID when you add the service principal and make the API call.

Reference [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/cloud-partner-portal-orig/cloud-partner-portal-api-troubleshooting-authentication-errors#forbidden-error).